# Coverage and Accuracy of rules from Induction trees

Tags: r

First, I created the following induction tree:

```
TrainTree <- rpart(decision~parents + has_nurs + form + children + housing + finance + social + health, data = Sets$training, method = "class")
rpart.plot(TrainTree, main = "Classification Tree showing Decision")
```

Which I then pruned:

```
printcp(TrainTree)
plotcp(TrainTree)
PruneTree <- prune(TrainTree, cp = 0.026)
rpart.plot(PruneTree, main = "Classification tree of pruned decision")
```

Next, I generated the rules using this R code:

```
rules <- rpart.rules(PruneTree)
```

Finally, I tried to determine the coverage and accuracy of the rules using:

```
coverage(rules, transactions = PruneTree)
```

In the end, I kept on getting the error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
> inherited method for function ‘coverage’ for signature ‘"rpart.rules"’

Could I get some help on how to determine the coverage or to solve this error, and also on how to determine the accuracy of the rules?